# If Statement with complex logic

Tags: formula

I have the formula which works as expected, but I wanted to add
`if listamount > 0 Opportunity name Upgrade`,
`if listamount < 0 Downgrade`,
`if = 0 then cancelation`

So I tried a couple of versions but could not get the result :( any thoughts?

```
IF(
    {!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__ListAmount__c < 0},
    'Downgrade' + " - " + 'Contract #' + "" + {!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.ContractNumber} 
        + " - " + {!$Record.Account.Name} + " - " + Text({!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.SBQQ__ExpirationDate__c}), 
    'Downgrade' + " - " + 'Contract #' + "" + {!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.ContractNumber} 
        + " - " + {!$Record.Account.AKA_Account_Name__c } + " - " + Text({!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.SBQQ__ExpirationDate__c})
)
```

Feedback:

** Based on suggestions,  I modified the formula and my expectation was When I amend a contract regarding the formula to get  proper  Opportunity name: (business decided don't use "Cancelation" only Upgrade and Downgrade and use net-amount instead list-amount)
`if Netamount > 0 Opportunity name Upgrade`,
`if Netamount < 0 Downgrade`,

```
IF({!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__NetAmount__c<0} ,
 'Downgrade',
'Upgrade'
+ " - " + 'Contract #' +""+{!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.ContractNumber}  +" - "+ {!$Record.Account.Name}+" - "+ Text({!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.SBQQ__ExpirationDate__c}))
```

The result is, When `ListAmount > 0 or <  0 Opportunity Name` is like
`Upgrade - Contract #00029859 - CALM-UAT - 2024-04-06`**

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your formula as _text_ instead of an image. Images are less accessible, and it's impossible to help you format your formula according to [formula best practices](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_formula_best_practices.htm&type=5) so that it's easier to read and understand.

Comment: Also, if you're encountering any error messages while trying to save this formula, please copy/paste them as well (don't try to shorten the error). If you're not getting any errors, then it'll be very helpful if you give us examples of the input data (`SBQQ__ListAmount__c`, `SBQQ__ExpirationDate__c`, etc...), the output that you're getting, and the output that you want.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Derek.

Comment: Not getting the error, but I cannot figure out how add 3 logics. Also the purpose of this formula When Opportunity Amends update an opportunity name based on List Amount through Record trigger flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Errata

After looking at the edit to the question, it seems like the issue is that the "merge field" parts improperly contained the comparison.

`{!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__ListAmount__c < 0}` is wrong
`{!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__ListAmount__c} < 0` is correct

Note that the `< 0` part moved to be *outside of the curly braces*. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

### On inequalities

One important thing to keep in mind when working with inequalities is what the opposite of your current inequality is.

- The opposite of `=` (equals) is `!=` (not equals)
- The opposite of `<` (less than) is `>=` (greater than or equals)
- The opposite of `>` (greater than) is `<=` (less than or equals)

### Applying that to the `IF()` function

When you use `IF(<condition>, <then expression>, <else expression>)`, if you get into the `<else expression>` part **then you know that the opposite of your condition is true**

```java
IF(
    /* condition */
    Some_Field__c < 11,
    
    /* then expression */
    /* In here, we know that Some_Field__c is less than 11 */
    "lower than 11, can count with fingers",

    /* else expression */
    /* In here, we know that Some_Field__c is greater than or equal to 11 */
    "I guess I need to start counting with my toes too"
)
```

If we focus on your current condition...

```java
/* Not a valid formula, just here for demonstration */
IF(
    {!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__ListAmount__c} < 0,
    /* ListAmount is less than 0 */,
    /* ListAmount is greater than or equal to 0 */
)
```

In the `<then expression>` you know enough to say that you want to use "Downgrade".
In the `<else expression>` you need to use another `IF()` so you have enough information to decide between "Upgrade" and "Cancellation"

```java
IF(
    {!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__ListAmount__c} < 0,
    "Downgrade",
    /* ListAmount is greater than or equal to 0 */
    /* Use another IF() to determine which scenario we're in */
    IF(
        {!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__ListAmount__c} > 0,
        /* ListAmount is strictly greater than 0 */,
        "Upgrade",
        /* ListAmount is neither less than nor greater than 0, so it must be */
        /*   exactly equal to 0 */
        "Cancellation"
    )
)
```

### Another tip to make your life easier

If you find you're repeating yourself in a formula (like you are with `" - " + 'Contract #' + "" + {!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.ContractNumber}`), then it's usually possible to "factor out" the parts that you're repeating.

So with your current formula, you could restructure it so it's like

```
<upgrade or downgrade part> 
+ <common part> 
+ <account name or aka account name> 
+ <another common part>
```

Applied to your existing formula

```java
IF(
    {!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__ListAmount__c} < 0,
    "Downgrade",
    /* I'm assuming that this should be "Upgrade" instead of "Downgrade" */
    "Upgrade"
)
+ " - " + "Contract #" + "" + {!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.ContractNumber} + " - " +
IF(
    {!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__ListAmount__c} < 0,
    {!$Record.Account.Name}
    {!$Record.Account.AKA_Account_Name__c }
)
+ " - " + Text({!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.SBQQ__ExpirationDate__c})
```

In this particular instance, this restructuring means you type 117 fewer characters.

I think this also makes it easier to modify your formula to add in the "Cancellation" scenario. That is to say that

```java
IF(
    {!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__ListAmount__c} < 0,
    "Downgrade",
    "Upgrade"
)
```

simply becomes

```java
IF(
    {!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__ListAmount__c} < 0,
    "Downgrade",
    IF(
        {!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__ListAmount__c} > 0,
        "Upgrade",
        "Cancellation"
    )
)
```

with the "common parts" not needing any modification, and a similar alteration being required for the part where you decide which Account Name to use.

Comment: Derek, Thank you so much! I really appreciate all your explanation. Based on your suggestion I could create Valid formula, like that:IF(
    {!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__ListAmount__c < 0},
    "Downgrade",
    IF(
        {!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__ListAmount__c > 0},
        "Upgrade",
        "Cancellation"
    )
) + " - " + "Contract #" + "" + {!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.ContractNumber} + " - " +
  
    {!$Record.Account.AKA_Account_Name__c }

+ " - " + Text({!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.SBQQ__ExpirationDate__c})

Comment: @UlviaJ Although comments are not great for code, after I copy/paste that, it looks right (as long as you want to use `{$Record.Account.AKA_Account_Name__c}` in all 3 scenarios). The `+ "" +` bit right after `"Contract #"` does nothing, so it should probably be removed. If your problem has been resolved, then it's customary to choose an answer and "accept" it (by clicking the check-mark). It's not mandatory, though it does signal to the community that you don't need further help. It also gives you +2 reputation (and +15 reputation for the person who wrote the answer).

Comment: Thank you Derek. I am testing now, will update this case shortly. Your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: @UlviaJ I've edited my answer based on your update. The quick summary is that you need to move the `< 0` to be outside of the curly braces. I.e. `{!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__NetAmount__c} < 0`

Comment: Hello Derek, Thank you all your help and time. I fixed the formula based on your comments. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(
    {!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__ListAmount__c < 0},
    "Downgrade",
    IF(
        {!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__ListAmount__c > 0},
        "Upgrade",
        "Cancellation"
    )
) + " - " + "Contract #" + "" + {!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.ContractNumber} + " - " +
  
    {!$Record.Account.AKA_Account_Name__c }

+ " - " + Text({!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.SBQQ__ExpirationDate__c})
```

Comment: Thank you for your first answer;  when answering with code, please use the formatting tools to make your answer readable

Comment: @derek, I used this formula and the formula is valid. However, It does not give the result as expected 
   IF({!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__NetAmount__c>0} ,
 'Upgrade',
'Downgrade'

+ " - " + 'Contract #' +""+{!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.ContractNumber}  +" - "+ {!$Record.Account.Name}+" - "+ Text({!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.SBQQ__ExpirationDate__c}))

Comment: IF({!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__NetAmount__c>0} ,
 'Upgrade',
'Downgrade'

+ " - " + 'Contract #' +""+{!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.ContractNumber}  +" - "+ {!$Record.Account.Name}+" - "+ Text({!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.SBQQ__ExpirationDate__c}))

Comment: I didn't get a notification (your @mention was incomplete). If my advice hasn't quite worked for you, then you should edit your question. Keep the existing text of your question, and just add what your formula looks like now and please go into detail (and provide examples) of the data on your record, the result you're getting, and the result you want (we won't know what result you want unless you explicitly tell us what it should look like).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to create an Opportunity Name based on certain conditions related to the NetAmount field from your Salesforce records. Your revised formula looks almost correct, but you're encountering an issue where the Opportunity Name is not being set correctly when the NetAmount is greater than 0.

The issue in your formula is in the 'Upgrade' part of the formula. You are trying to concatenate the text 'Upgrade' with other values without the proper separation. To fix this, you should concatenate 'Upgrade' with the other text using the ampersand (&) symbol. Here's the corrected formula:

```
IF({!$Record.SBQQ__PrimaryQuote__r.SBQQ__NetAmount__c < 0},
    'Downgrade',
    'Upgrade' & " - " & 'Contract #' & "" & {!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.ContractNumber} & " - " & {!$Record.Account.Name} & " - " & TEXT({!$Record.SBQQ__AmendedContract__r.SBQQ__ExpirationDate__c})
)
```

This formula should correctly set the Opportunity Name as "Upgrade - Contract #00029859 - CALM-UAT - 2024-04-06" when the NetAmount is greater than or equal to 0 and as "Downgrade" when the NetAmount is less than 0.